# How to make a dataframe using list in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a dataframe with a specific name.

Now I have a fileList:

```
> fileList

[1] "ml17_280_Glide_Day1-1.1_10Hz.txt" "ml17_280_Glide_Day1-1.1_15Hz.txt"
[3] "ml17_280_Glide_Day1-1.1_20Hz.txt" "ml17_280_Glide_Day1-1.1_25Hz.txt"
[5] "ml17_280_Glide_Day1-1.1_5Hz.txt"
```

fileList[i] represents a name of each dataframe including numeric values, and I would like to make another dataframe by

```
dat <- fileList[i]
```

But, this results in as below

```
> dat
[1] "ml17_280_Glide_Day1-1.1_10Hz.txt"
```

How can I copy the dataframe to another?

Comment: Did you mean `dat <- read.table(fileList[i])` ? Are they files or they are dataframe objects in R?

Comment: Relevant post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once

Comment: Thank you for your comment. They are dataframe objects in R.

Comment: Then maybe `dat <- get(fileList[i])` ?

Comment: This works! I really appreciate your help! Thank you very much.